# Why is this JSON parser not working?

Tags: android, json

Everytime I try opening the app, it says

```
"Unfortunately, (appName) has stopped."
```

I'm trying to parse some json data, and display it in the "ram" textView, but it's not working. What am I doing wrong?

```
public class Index extends Activity {
TextView ram = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.RAM_Text);
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        DefaultHttpClient   httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(new BasicHttpParams());
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://admin.isdata.dk/jscalls/dashboard.php?auth=215e82a271f225df31ce2c358ec26a49");
        httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

        InputStream inputStream = null;
        String result = null;
        try {
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);           
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

            inputStream = entity.getContent();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            result = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) { 
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            try{if(inputStream != null)inputStream.close();}catch(Exception squish){}
        }
        JSONObject jObject = null;
        try {
            jObject = new JSONObject(result);
        } catch (JSONException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            double aJsonDouble = jObject.getDouble("ram");
            String valueOfRam = String.valueOf(aJsonDouble);
            ram.setText(valueOfRam);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }



}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should not run this code in your onCreate method. Put it in an AsyncTask so it works in the background and doesn't slow down your app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change to

```
TextView ram; 
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ram = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.RAM_Text);
```

Also

```
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

Should be in a `Thread` or `Asynctask`.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

All network related operation should be done on a `thread` or `Asynctask`